# Does center of gravity of Solar system influence intensity of space rays reaching earth, space dust, speed of earth rotation?

Tags: gravity, solar-system

I found an interesting article, claiming very interesting things. But I cannot find any trust-worty sources confirming such bold claims. Maybe someone came across some solid proof?

1) Center of gravity of Solar system periodically changes from almost the center of the sun to far towards sun surface (depending on planet movement)

Oscillation of the position of Center of gravity influences the following:

2) The closer Center of gravity to sun center, the more the intensity of Space rays reaching earth

2.1) Intensity of Space rays reaching earth increases water condensation in earth atmosphere (thus we have more clouds), so
2.2) Higher Intensity of Space rays makes lower temperature in near-earth-surface atmosphere (as we have more clouds), lower Intensity of Space rays makes climate warmer (less clouds).

3) The closer Center of gravity to the sun center, the more space dust (and small meteorites) gets into our atmosphere which decreases its opacity

4) Position of Center of gravity also influences speed of earth (24-hour) rotation (thru atmospheric effects as well).

[Source (Russian)](https://snob.ru/selected/entry/12156)

Comment: Can you double-check the link you provided? It might have been pasted in wrong.

Comment: The link now works, sorry. But this is not anything authoritative, I don't think the author is a big specialist in the field...

Comment: What are "space rays?"  Solar wind?  "Regular" solar radiation?  Gamma rays?

Comment: If Google Translate is of any use, the linked article is from 2010 and predicts a "serious cooling" event in 2013/14, even freezing the Bosporus, _which didn't occur._ Many arguments seem to be extremely oversimplified.